# Emacs - regular expressions in Lisp need to be double-escaped - why?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I've been playing around with emacs lisp, and I wanted to write a little function to do a regular expression search and replace.  I had a heck of a time getting the regular expression to work correctly because I didn't realize that all the special characters need to be double escaped when writing lisp code (but not when using query-replace-regexp interactively!).

So for example, using query-replace-regexp interactively you can use

```
^\(.*\)[\t]-.*$
```

but when writing elisp code you need to double escape everything like so:

```
^\\(.*\\)[\t]-.*$
```

I finally found a reference to this in a Steve Yegge [article](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/effective-emacs#item9), but I was wondering if anyone knew why this is?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's because you need to escape backslashes in strings.  If you don't escape the backslash of `\(` in the string, it turns out to be just `(`

Comment: Dang, the backslash escape thing just got me when I posted that :) I had to put \\\\\( to get it right

Comment: The same thing is true of any language that doesn't have direct syntactic support for regexes and constructs them via string literals (e.g., Java, Javascript), right?

Comment: That's true Chris.  I think I was thrown off in elisp because I wasn't used to escaping () and {} chars.

Comment: @KevinTighe: note that in Emacs-26 the backslash in things like `\{` is highlighted in red to indicate that it's a likely error (because such a backslash doesn't do anything).

Answer (score 19):

You already have the answer, but a built-in aide for creating regular expressions inside Emacs is re-builder.

```
M-x re-builder
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about that.  Next time I do this it should go much more smoothly.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 10):

scottfrazier is correct, one escape is parsed when the string is read, another is parsed when creating the regular expression. It's fairly easy to remember, but it can become a pain, especially when you're trying to match a literal backslash '\'. You end up having to do it four times '\\\\' because you have to double-slash to match the slash in both the initial string parse and the regular expression parse.

And when you write on Stack Overflow about this problem you have to use [8 slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/viewmarkup/711214) because markdown uses the slash for an escape character as well.

Answer (score 8):

FWIW, `emacs-lisp-mode` will fontify the special expressions (like
`\\(` and `\\)` for you.  You can then change the faces to be
something that stands out.

(They are `font-lock-regexp-grouping-construct` and `font-lock-regexp-grouping-backslash`)