# Emacs VHDL jump to error

Tags: emacs, vhdl

I cannot make emacs to jump to next-error, previous-error, first-error in vhdl-mode.

I am using FSF Emacs 23.3.1 with recent vhdl-mode 3.33.28 under ubuntu.
I can compile with Modelsim and I get compiler error list:

```
-- Loading package standard
-- ...
-- Compiling entity foo
** Error: path/foo.vhd(22): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "std_olgic".
```

I tried to adapt error regexp (in compiler-setup) to the simplest one:

```
 \*\* Error: \([a-zA-Z\/_.]*\)(\([0-9]*\)).*
```

When I use it this way I can see that it parses errors correctly:

```
 sed "s/\*\* Error: \([a-zA-Z\/_.]*\)(\([0-9]*\)).*/\1 \2/"  ...
 path/foo.vhd 22
```

I changed "File subexp index" and "Line subexp index" respectively to 1 and 2 but still I cannot jump around errors.

Comment: I think this feature is not supported in emacs23, but only in emacs21 that is pretty old by now.

Answer (score 2):

The following config resolves this bug for me

```
'(vhdl-compile-use-local-error-regexp t)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist '("** Error: \\(.+\\)(\\([0-9]*\\)):" 1 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs regexps, you need to double-escape parens in a string ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538842/emacs-regular-expressions-in-lisp-need-to-be-double-escaped-why/538874#538874)).  Try something like this: `\*\* Error: \\([a-zA-Z0-9/_.]+\\)(\\([0-9]+\\)).*`

Comment: Thx for reply, but it is still not working. It looks like it is completely disable regardless what I put in regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump an old topic but I just ran into this issue and got things to work out for me.

Here are the settings I used to get it to work:

Regexp:

```
\(ERROR\|WARNING\|\*\* Error\|\*\* Warning\)[^:]*:\( *[[0-9]+]\)? \(.+\)(\([0-9]+\)):
```

File subexp index: 3

Line subexp index: 4

Vhdl Compile Use Local Error Regexp (under Vhdl Compile group): Off

And here's my story about it:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t957495-emacs-vhdl-mode-next-error-previous-error-and-first-error-are-not-working.html

:P

Hope this helps!