# how to get emacs to treat a matplotlibrc as a sh-mode

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to get emacs to treat a `matplotlibrc` file as sh-mode for reasonable syntax highlighting.

Adding these variations to my `user.el` fails to work:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("*matplotlibrc'" . sh-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("matplotlibrc'" . sh-mode))
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that it works if you escape the single quote:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("matplotlibrc\\'" . sh-mode))
```

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash):

> `\'` matches the empty string, but only at the end of the buffer or string being matched against.

And because it's Emacs Lisp, you [need to double the backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538874/354577).